# Django model not working through admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin-actions, django-webtest

I am working on a auction site using django project. I have a model for placing bid. I have registered the model in admin.py , but when I try to place bid from admin interface it is not updating in the main website page. But through website the bid is updating perfectly and other models are working perfectly.

**models.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models

CHOICES = (
    ('fashion','Fashion'),
    ('tools', 'Tools'),
    ('toys','Toys'),
    ('electronics','Electronics'),
    ('home accesories','Home accessories'),
    ('books','Books'),
)
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Bid(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    listingid = models.IntegerField()
    bid = models.IntegerField()

class Listing(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=CHOICES, default='fashion')
    link = models.CharField(max_length=10000,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=64, default= datetime.now().strftime(" %d %B %Y %X "))

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=64, default= datetime.now().strftime(" %d %B %Y %X "))
    comment = models.TextField()
    listingid = models.IntegerField()
```

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User, Listing, Bid, Comment

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Bid)
admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Listing)
admin.site.register(Comment)
```

This is the function for bidsubmit in **views.py** (I have imported Bid model in this file):

```
def bidsubmit(request,listingid):
    current_bid = Listing.objects.get(id=listingid)
    current_bid = current_bid.price
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_bid = int(request.POST.get('bid'))
        if user_bid > current_bid:
            listing_items = Listing.objects.get(id=listingid)
            listing_items.price = user_bid
            listing_items.save()
            try:
                if Bid.objects.filter(id=listingid):
                    bidrow = Bid.objects.filter(id=listingid)
                    bidrow.delete()
                b = Bid()
                b.user=request.user.username
                b.title = listing_items.title
                b.listingid = listingid
                b.bid = user_bid
                b.save()
            except:
                b = Bid()
                b.user=request.user.username
                b.title = listing_items.title
                b.listingid = listingid
                b.bid = user_bid
                b.save()
            
            response = redirect('auctions:listingpage',id=listingid)
            response.set_cookie('errorgreen','bid successful!!!',max_age=3)
            return response
        else :
            response = redirect('auctions:listingpage',id=listingid)
            response.set_cookie('error','Bid should be greater than current price',max_age=3)
            return response
    else:
        return redirect('auctions:index')
```

Comment: Make sure you have run these commands before running suerver `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Can you show your GetBid function?
Are you deleting the old bid from the database while adding a bid from your admin panel.
Because you are doing so in your normal bidsubmit function.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have registered your app in your project `settings.py` (append your app name which includes your `Bid` model in `INSTALLED_APPS`) and then run it's related management commands (i.e. `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`). I hope this will solve your problem.